# CSS Style rules not being overridden if first in the list

Tags: html, css

So in my CSS file, I have some styles for some inputs:

```
div.playerForm input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="submit"], input[type="date"], input[type="checkbox"] {
background-color: rgb(195, 59, 34);
font-weight: 900;
color: rgb(245, 240, 224);

border-color: rgb(245, 240, 224);
border-width: 0.8vw;
border-radius: 0.8vw;
border-style: inset;
padding: 0.3vw; 
}
```

Now I am also using a rule to use some fixed values when the screen size gets to a certain size:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
div.playerForm input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="submit"], input[type="date"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 3.0px;
    border-width: 9.6px;
    border-radius: 9.6px;
    padding: 3.6px;
}
```

However, when inspecting the code on my website, the rules for `input[type="text"]` are not being overridden and so the border continues to grow, however all the other input types abide to this rule.

If I swap the order in the first block of code above, so that `input[type="number"]` is now the first in the list, the issue now happens with that, and `input[type="text"]` behaves as it should.

How do I make sure every element in this list is overridden, not just everything after the first?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` for your media query - not sure if that's a typo just on here or in your actual code

Comment: You have the first input prefixed with div.playerForm, all the other inputs are global styles.

Comment: @dantheman Ahh I see, is there a way to make all inputs in the list be prefixed with div.playerForm without actually typing that out for each one?

Comment: @MattHamer5 that is just from where I have copied the code

Comment: @LukeBurston if you're using css then you have to prefix each one. If you use scss then you can use nesting.